# Storing a global object in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I'm currently building a rather large ASP.NET MVC application with user logins. Some methods/functions are restricted to users of a certain type/role (*not* the regular ASP.NET Role, though) and when running these functions, I have to check in the database if the current, logged in user has access to perform the given task.

As you probably can imaging, this leads to quite a few calls to the database, to get the person. So, currently, for every page load and every restricted method, I'm making this call:

```
var person = ctx.People
             Include("Person_Firm_PersonResponsibility.Firm")
             .Include("Person_Firm_PersonResponsibility.PersonResponsibility")
             .Include("Person_Firm_PersonOption.PersonOption")
             .Include(x => x.City)
             .Include(x => x.Country)
             .FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == personId);
```

Since I need all of these informations for globally displayed data.

Is there any way to simply make this call once (i.e. when a user logs in) and then store that object somewhere for later use? Obviously, a Session variable could be used, but since the person object contains some sensitive data, I'm not sure if that would be a good idea ;-)

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would session be a bad place?

Comment: You could use the session object, it only lives on the server and I'm not aware of any vector attack you may suffer.

Comment: another possible solution could be to use standard Asp.Net Cache with generated cache key 'User'+ user.Id

Comment: There is a security issue with your approach (no matter what storage you use) - you can't prevent the user from performing the action by revoking their access to that action as long as they keep their session alive.

Comment: @svinja Yes I can ;-) since I perform the "IsAdministrator" check on the database for every restricted method. I got that one covered. So the Session object cannot be hijacked? That's what I've heard :-)

Comment: If you use https, it is unlikely someone will hijack a session. However, this is not really relevant to your question. Hijacking a session does not give you access to the session data stored on the server. Think of session hijacking as using someone's computer while they're away from keyboard - it has basically the same effect. The original user couldn't see the server-side session data, and neither can you.

Comment: Ahh, got'ya :-) Guess you learn something new every day. I think I'll go with a session variable then. Seems the easiest way. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the scope that you wish to have, you can use:

- Session: for the current user, in the current navigation session (no other user can see it);
- Cache: for all users, with a fixed expiration;
- Application: for all users, with no expiration.

For cache and application, the key might be composed by some user property, such as id or login.
These guys (https://efcache.codeplex.com/) have implemented a second level cache for Entity Framework, might be worth checking it out.

Comment: Thanks, Ricardo :-) But isn't Session variable a bit 'fragile'? I'm afraid of hackers here since this is a *very* large system with a lot of sensitive data.

Comment: How come? I think it is very safe. They would have to know the cookie stored in the user's machine and send it. It's basically how authentication is implemented, and you probably don't think it's insecure.

Comment: Good point :-) I have absolutely no clue why I've always thought, that a Session variable would be insecure. Been a developer for 6 years now with that idealogy :-D Glad I saw the light, though.